# Ionic 4 - How to change modal background to transparent?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to create a modal with transparent background but it is not working

```css
ion-content {
  --background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.closeBtn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <h3 class="ion-text-center">
    <strong>Test.</strong>
  </h3>
  <ion-button class="closeBtn" color='light' fill='clear'>Close</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

I expect to see some transparency.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

global.css

```css
.modal-wrapper{
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

page.scss

```
ion-content{
    --background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

you can do it with changing `--ion-background-color` variable of `ion-modal`:

```css
ion-modal {
  --ion-background-color: #ffffff85;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but also it did not solve my problem.

Comment: This worked for me. I applied it in the scoped style of my modal component.

Answer (score 3):

**global.scss**

```css
.modal-wrapper, .inner-scroll {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

**your page.scss**

```css
ion-content {
 --background: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just:

```
ion-content {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: I already tried this strategy before it didn't work well because of pre-defined css variables written by ionic. anw thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply a css class to your modal (here phone-modal) and then override the ionic basic styles in your global.scss

```
        const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create(
        {
            component: PhoneContactModalComponent,
            cssClass: 'phone-modal'
        });
```

global.scss :

```
.phone-modal {
    padding: 35vh 30px 20vh 30px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.sc-ion-modal-md-h {
    --background: none;
}
.sc-ion-modal-ios-h {
    --background: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it really worked but i want to target all the modal container not only modal-md-h or modal-ios-h, but this is a good solution +1